# object is not callable error when creating a form in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am using django and trying to create a registration form and below are my codes

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

attrs_dict = { 'class': 'required' }

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$',
                                max_length=30,
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),
                                label=_(u'username'))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict,maxlength=75)),
                                label=_(u'email address'))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict, render_value=False),
                                label=_(u'password'))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict, render_value=False),
                                label=_(u'password (again)'))
```

**views.py**

```
from authentication.forms import RegistrationForm

def register(request):
    regsiter_form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = regsiter_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'], 
                                                email=request.POST['email'], 
                                                password=request.POST['password1'])
            new_user.is_active = False
            new_user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    return render_to_response('registration/registration_form.html'{'form':regsiter_form})
```

so when we go to the url,a registration form is displaying and when we enter the details and clicked submit i am getting the following error

```
TypeError at /accounts_register/register/
'RegistrationForm' object is not callable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts_register/register/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'RegistrationForm' object is not callable
```

**Traceback**

```
▶ Local vars
/home/user/package/authentication/views.py in register
        form = regsiter_form(request.POST)
```

So can anyone please let me know why the above form object is complaining as the object is not callable and where we need to make the changes in order to avoid this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
def register(request):
    register_form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'], 
                                            email=request.POST['email'], 
                                            password=request.POST['password1'])
            new_user.is_active = False
            new_user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    return render_to_response('registration/registration_form.html'{'form':register_form})
```

So, `form = register_form(request.POST)` should be `form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)` inside your POST check.

The point is you first created an object/instance of RegistrationForm using `register_form = RegistrationForm()`, and then you tried `register_form(request.POST)`, so basically you are trying to again call an object/instance which is not allowed unless there is a `__call__` method defined on your class.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
form = regsiter_form(request.POST)
```

do

```
regsiter_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
```

And use `register_form` object instead of `form`.

Also, use data from `form.cleaned_data` to create user object instead of from `request.POST`

As

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'] ...)
```